# UIImage Difficulty

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I'm using the `HSImageSidebarView` and in the example included in the open source project, this is how to load the images in the sidebar :

```
-(UIImage *)sidebar:(HSImageSidebarView *)sidebar imageForIndex:(NSUInteger)anIndex {
    int color = [[colors objectAtIndex:anIndex] intValue];
    switch (color % 3) {
        case 0:
            return [UIImage imageNamed:@"Blue"];
            break;
        case 1:
            return [UIImage imageNamed:@"Red"];
            break;
        default:
            return [UIImage imageNamed:@"Green"];

    }
}
```

What my problem is how to add my own images from the `NSDocumentDirectory`. Here is my array :

```
self.images = [NSMutableArray new];  
for(int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) 
{ 
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Images%d.png", i]]; 
    NSLog(@"savedImagePath=%@",savedImagePath);

    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:savedImagePath]){ 
        [images addObject:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:savedImagePath]]; 
        NSLog(@"file exists");
    } 
    NSLog(@"file does not exist");
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: ..anddd? What's the problem? Is your `savedImagePath` correct? Does the file exist? And FYI, in your loop it will say everytime `file does not exist` because you didn't encapsulate it in an `else` statement.

Comment: My array is fine.What my prob is,I don't know how to add it in the `-(UIImage *)sidebar:(HSImageSidebarView *)sidebar imageForIndex:(NSUInteger)anIndex`

Comment: if you down voted me, please leave a comment

Comment: Seems to me like you need to go back a few steps and get a more solid idea on programming before continuing. This is a rather simple thing that you should be able to figure out yourself, otherwise you are gonna have a lot of difficulties ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would do something like this.

```
-(UIImage *)sidebar:(HSImageSidebarView *)sidebar imageForIndex:(NSUInteger)anIndex {

    return (UIImage*)[self.images objectAtIndex:anIndex];

}
```

You're storing `UIImage`'s into your `images` array already. So there is no need to use the `-imageNamed:` method like the example. Instead what you do is return the image at said index from your `images` array with the `objectAtIndex:` method.

Hope this helps.